# Apple RealityKit & AVFoundation Simultaneously Issue

Tags: swift, avfoundation, arkit, realitykit

I'm trying to create an app that uses RealityKit with the back camera (ARWorldTrackingConfiguration) for AR content and uses AVFoundation to capture the front camera allowing to adjust the AR content by analyzing the face of the user.

Is this possible?

I was expecting to make both cameras work simultaneously, one using RelityKit and other using AVFoundation.
Separately the components work but simultaneously they do not.